# Reuse other app's icon in my app?

Tags: ios-appstore

Do I violate any rule / law when I reuse other apps icon as my app icon?

What if I modify image a bit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the legalities of reusing someone else's intellectual property, it is not specific to the topic of this site even if the property in question in this case is a Mac/iOS app icon.

Comment: We're not a good place to ask about laws. Jurisdiction matters, as does case law as does dozens of factors. Could you make this more specific or are you really looking to simply rip off another piece of art and then sell it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most companies will have their icons as trademarks:

> A trademark is any word, name, symbol, or design, or any combination
>   thereof, used in commerce to identify and distinguish the goods of one
>   manufacturer or seller from those of another and to indicate the
>   source of the goods. See 15 U.S.C. § 1127.

Trademarks are protected and you can be sued for infringement. See: [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark)

What you're asking about boils down to theft.

Ultimately, you need to consult a lawyer, not Stack Exchange, as this is a legal question, not a technical question.

Comment: What if I modify image a bit?

Comment: There's no way to answer that question, definitively. Whether what you're proposing will work out depends on, (1) does the original creator notice? (2) do they object? (3) if they request that Apple block your app from the App Store, does Apple take your side or theirs? (4) if they sue you for trademark infringement, does the court take your side or theirs?

Comment: To take a more common example - start producing a soda using Coke's logo and see how far you get. Doing this deliberately is close to fraud as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are such things as copyrights which also apply to app icons. So yes, you will break the law pretty much everywhere in the world.

If in doubt, consult a lawyer.

Comment: I would add - just ask the owner of the original app. If they give you permission, then no harm. If so, get another icon. Seems pretty straightforward and solvable by asking any toddler or person in kindergarten to sort out the right and wrong here.